# Does reading a c++ 11 book requires to have knowledge of c++98?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98

I am currently reading a C++ book written in 2000 which basically means is using c++ 98.(correct me if I am wrong)

My question is, reading a c++11 book like this one (https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321563840) which most of the users suggest, requires me to have read already a c++98 book?

Comment: That book covers the entire language, not just the new stuff.

Comment: depends on book -- i.e. the last edition of TC++PL does not need you other reading.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves a down-vote

Comment: No, you should now learn C++11 if you are a young programmer looking to learn C++ because while you get a real job C++11/14 will be standard... if you are programming for living atm it is still good to learn C++11 but you need to be aware of things not avaliable in C++98 so you can modify existing C++ code that is being compiled on legacy compilers

Comment: Keep in mind that TCPL is not a book for beginners (as the author himself mentions)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl "while you get a real job C++11/14 will be standard" You're kidding right? In some places, but where I am (and it's a pretty big place) compiler upgrades are glacial, because we have to support a wide variety of platforms. (I'm looking at you, Oracle).

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: "while you get a real job C++11/14 will be standard". Umm, are you saying the dude won't find a job for the next 5 years? I mean it took two years for gcc team to implement most of the new features, MS support for C++11 is lacking, so it'll be a LONG time till the new standard becomes widely adopted.

Comment: @SigTerm C++14 is a minor upgrade so it will be done fast

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: (IMO) It'll still take 3..5 more years till C++11 gets widely adopted and even after that time there'll be some software that will keep using older standard. The big problem at the moment is that Microsoft/Intel do not support C++11 fully and GCC.I doubt that OP won't be able to find job for that long...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

C++11 is not a separate language. It's just a new version of the existing one. Reading a C++11 book requires whatever prior knowledge that the C++11 book says it requires.

Bjarne's new version of "The C++ Programming Language" expects no prior knowledge of anything. Some other books will expect prior knowledge.

Comment: I guess it expects prior knowledge of how to read...

Comment: Nico Josuttis' book http://www.cppstdlib.com/ also explains things clearly to a beginner. There is no harm in reading an old book if it's any good though.

Comment: @doctorlove I thought that was really a reference book for the library, not a language tutorial aimed at beginners?

Comment: @BoBTFish Yes, it's a reference not a tutorial book.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, given the changes from C++98 to C++11, I'd recommend **not** reading an old book beforehand.

This is because a lot of old methods and idioms have been replaces with much neater constructs and features, which avoid many pitfalls and issues that C++ programmers had to contend with earlier. A coarse comparison would be to read up on relays and electron/vacuum tubes in order to, eventually, understand how to build transistor based logic. No need to start at that end.

So, I recommend you want to read on what's current, then it wouldn't hurt to read an older book to understand why a lot of already existing C++ code was written like it was.

If it's an "what's new in C++11", then you obviously need to know C++98 beforehand.

But as @Nicol says, the book should declare what previous requirements it has.